# Broadleaf Commerce User Administration Doc

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

i want to know about user permissions in broadleaf admin and how to create them ? I can't find any documentation about related user administration. Please guide me on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of now many docs are not available in Broadleaf documentation site for the latest releases(version 3.0 being current). May be this is what you are looking for [AdminUser](http://javadocs.broadleafcommerce.com/core/2.2.0-GA/org/broadleafcommerce/openadmin/client/security/AdminUser.html).

There is an admin user class and an interface. The interface extends AdminSecurityContext interface. You can set and get the user roles with the following methods,

```
public Set<AdminRole> getAllRoles();
public void setAllRoles(Set<AdminRole> allRoles);
```

Edit:

http://javadocs.broadleafcommerce.com/core/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org/broadleafcommerce/openadmin/server/security/remote/AdminUser.html

Comment: Great link, although that is not actually what i looking for. But i got Admin permission specifications from that.